# npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve. When I ran npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

When I run 'npm install' to install the dependencies from a cloned repository I get the error below from the terminal. I use windows 10

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@4.0.0
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"4.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@4.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@3.9.10
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@4.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"4.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\USER-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-04T10_18_32_
```

Even when I ran `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` I still get same error. Please what could possibly be wrong?

And here's the content in my package.json file:

```
}
 ]
  "name": "info-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of node and npm are You using ?

Comment: Node version - v16.14.0    npm version 8.19.1 @MarioG8

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that `react-scripts@4.0.0` supports `typescript@^3.2.1` (i.e. TypeScript >=3.2.1, <4) as a peer dependency.

Your dev dependencies have TypeScript 4 (not 3.2.x) in them, which is not supported by that version of react-scripts, hence the resolution error.

The [current version of react-scripts is 5.0.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts), so I'd recommend upgrading react-scripts to that version (simply by changing that `"4.0.0"` in your package.json to `"5.0.1"`) and trying again, since [that version declares support for TypeScript 4](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/package.json#L86-L89).

Comment: However, when I run ```npm start ``` I get this error: ```Error: Cannot find module 'side-channel'```. Then I tried to install the module with: ```npm i side-channel``` command, and it returned ```npm ERR! Invalid Version: ``` @AKX